# Getting BeforeProperties for User field in ItemUpdating or ItemUpdated Event Receiver

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, event-receivers

I am trying to get the BeforeProperties for an User field in a custom list on ItemUpdating or ItemUpdated Event Receiver.
i always getting 'null' on the before value

```
String Olds = properties.BeforeProperties["PILOTE_x0020_ROCESSUS"].ToString();

SPFieldUserValue Old = new SPFieldUserValue(mySite, Olds);

OldUser = Old.User;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's expected for standard lists (not document libraries). You can get the original value from `properties.ListItem` in ItemUpdating and the changed value from `properties.AfterProperties`.

I guess you are using claims based authentication. There are some differences what `BeforeProperties` for user field contains depending what type of authentication is used and depending is the field updated with the UI or programmatically. I have done some testing some time ago and included the results in my post

https://naimmurati.wordpress.com/2014/07/25/user-field-in-event-receivers-when-using-claims-based-authentication-and-classic-mode-authentication/